# Ошибка elasticsearch на laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Развернул проект на laravel использующий elasticsearch.
Запустил elasticsearch на windows.

В консоли:

```
   Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\InvalidArgumentException  : Could not parse URI

  at C:\OSPanel\domains\laraboard\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder.php
: 669
  665:     {
  666:         $parts = parse_url($host);
  667:
  668:         if ($parts === false) {
  669:             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Could not parse URI");
  670:         }
  671:
  672:         if (isset($parts['port']) !== true) {
  673:             $parts['port'] = 9200;
  674:         }

  Exception trace:

  1   Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::extractURIParts("http://")
      C:\OSPanel\domains\laraboard\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder.ph
p : 625

  2   Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::buildConnectionsFromHosts()
      C:\OSPanel\domains\laraboard\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder.ph
p : 562

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Что делать ? как исправить?

Comment: а что вы передаете в $host?

Comment: вот я тоже пытаюсь понять. видимо что то не то передаю

Comment: я думал, очевидно же, у вас вываливается ошибка, потому что `parse_url` не может распарсить вставляемый вами url сервера эластика

Answer (score 0):

В файл .env

```
ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED=true
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost:9200
```